Does altering particle direction constitute work?
Given a moving charged particle entering magnetic field and therefore changing direction as a result, yet still the energy of the particle remains the same. Did the magnetic field perform work that can be quantified? If yes, where the energy came from?

No. Magnetic forces do no work on charged particles as the Lorentz force is always perpendicular to velocity.

Much appreciated the prompt answer
And in particular case of completely reversing particle's movement, no momentum will be passed from particle to the magnetic field? In other words, mf interactions are frictionless, lossless and "workless"?

@AndreiBronnikov momentum is exchanged, just not energy

Two similar setups: a spaceship in vacuum, with a magnetic field gap strong enough to rotate a proton 180 degrees and the same ship with a positively charged plate instead. In both cases incoming proton will be sent back and the spaceship's momentum will be increased by MpV ( twice the momentum of incoming proton). Work is by definition a change in momentum. Am I missing something here?
